# Чи можна сказати "приготувати нашвидкуруч" одним словом?

Tags: переклад, from-english, синоніми, одним-словом

Перекладаю з англійської і стикнулася із тим, що хочеться дібрати якийсь короткий синонім до *"приготувати нашвидкуруч"*, однак не можу ніде знайти відповідний варіант.

Оригінальне речення: *"Betty whips up freshly baked pies when the mood strikes"*.

Comment: Варто зауважити, що *"to whip up"* — то є phrasal verb, і воно за означенням не відповідає потребі щодо передачі змісту одним словом. Можливо, варто відмовитися від такої вимоги як від занадто сильної? В сенсі, шукати саме «короткий синонім» (як у тексті запитання), а не «одним словом» (як у tag).

Comment: Можливо Ви праві, дякую

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вам може підійти одне із цих слів:

[скапарити](http://sum.in.ua/s/skaparyty)

> 1. Мати вибачливо подивилась на Марка, метнулась до кабиці, щоб скапарити сяку-таку вечерю (Михайло Стельмах, Правда.., 1961, 33).

[спарто́лити](http://sum.in.ua/s/spartolyty)

> Жінка вже спартолила пісний борщ з самісінької ботвини та сирівцю (Нечуй-Левицький, IV, 1956, 319).

Comment: Теж думав про ці слова, але не наважився написати відповідь, бо вони все ж мають підтекст неякісного результату тоді як та пані, мабуть, робить чудові і смачні пироги. Ммм... ))

Comment: Дійсно, у тексті немає негативної конотації, однак дякую за відповідь все одно